# Apache+Flask, when I use flask-mail, SMTPSenderRefused occured

Tags: python, apache, flask

Here is the code snippet of config:

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = '465'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'my email here'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password here'
```

When I test without Apache, all the code worked well,but when I test with **Apache**, **SMTPSenderRefused** occured.

This is the entire error info:

*SMTPSenderRefused: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 s23sm10937096pfj.86 - gsmtp',*

It seemed the password wasn't passed to gmail.

Is it the problem of apache? 
Thank you!

Comment: Both are Ubuntu, but different machines.

Comment: I give up flask mail and use the standard module smtplib instead. Then it works.

Comment: I will try to figure out the cause of the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it's not my personal project. Really sorry about that.